# Glassfish so many FileNotFoundException on server startup

Tags: java, glassfish, dependency-management, filenotfoundexception

I have an ear file. I start my glassfish domain and deploy using an ide (IDEA or eclipse). On server start up when I check the logs I see a FileNotFoundException for I believe each and every dependency we have on the project.

Sample :

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\Developer\web-server\glassfish3.1.2\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\AYDEMPANOTEST-EAR.ear\spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
>   (The system cannot find the file specified)

I use maven for dependency managment. After a set of FileNotFoundExceptions the final log confirms that the domain started successfully and the project is deployed as expected.

Sample :

> [#|2014-02-06T14:20:16.648+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=45;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|AYDEMPANOTEST-EAR.ear
>   was successfully deployed in 23,440 milliseconds.|#]

The project works and behaves fine however I'm still very curious about why we have so many exceptions thrown that can be observed in the logs and why they have no effect at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it's a known TLD scanning bug that is fixed on glassfish 4.0.